# Laravel custom validation check other field provided in parameters

Tags: php, laravel

I want to make custom validator in addition to required_without to also fail if all field is filled.

Current rules:

```
'foo' => 'required_without:baz',
'bar' => 'required_without:baz',
'baz' => 'required_without_all:foo,bar',
```

Will result:

1. Foo, Bar, and Baz are all empty (error)
2. One of Foo / Bar is filled, the other are empty (error)
3. Foo and Bar are filled, Baz is empty (OK)
4. Foo and Bar are empty, Baz is filled (OK)
5. Foo Bar, and Baz are filled (OK) **← I want this to become error instead**

So I'm creating [custom validator using extend](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#using-extensions), and want to use it like this:

```
'foo' => 'required_without:bar|empty_if_present:baz',
'bar' => 'required_without:foo|empty_if_present:baz',
'baz' => 'required_without_all:foo,bar|empty_if_present:foo,bar',
```

AppServiceProvider.php

```
Validator::extend('empty_if_present', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
    $attributeIsNotEmpty = !empty($value);
    $paramsAreEmpty = true;

    foreach ($parameters as $param) {
        // how do I check if Foo and Bar are empty??
        if ($param is not empty) {
            $paramsAreEmpty = false;
        }
    }

    return $attributeIsNotEmpty && $paramsAreEmpty;
}, 'The :attribute must be empty if :fields is present.');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you want

```php
Validator::extend('empty_if_present', static function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
    $attributeIsNotEmpty = ! empty($value);
    $paramsAreEmpty = true;

    foreach ($parameters as $param) {
        // how do I check if Foo and Bar are empty??
        if (! empty(request()->input($param))) {
            $paramsAreEmpty = false;
        }
    }

    return $attributeIsNotEmpty && $paramsAreEmpty;
}, 'The :attribute must be empty if :fields is present.');
```

Comment: I just wanted to comment about the edit as it fails my unit test, but foreach works

Comment: yea I realized it check both fields so I removed it earlier